# Defining data source in connectionstring when instance of SQL Server Express is different on 2 computers

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-express

I work on an ASP.NET MVC solution with my colleague. Each one works on his own computer. My instance of SQL Server Express is called `SQLEXPRESS`, while his instance is the default (local) instance.

My connection string in `web.config` is like this:

```
<add name="Prog.Models.BreezeContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Prog;Integrated Security=True"/>
```

At this time, my colleague needs to change the connection string to this:

```
<add name="Prog.Models.BreezeContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Prog;Integrated Security=True"/>
```

You will notice the difference in the datasource: `.\SQLEXPRESS` <> `(local)`

**My question**: how can we proceed to be able to avoid changing the connection string each time we run the app? I don't want to uninstall/reinstall my SQL Server Express to have a local instance. I wonder if there is another option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two config files which are specific to each machine and use a pre-build script to determine which one to use.

e.g. you can have two connectionstrings.config files, connectionstrings.bronzato.config and connectionstrings.colleague.config, each with the environment specific settings.

In the pre-build script you can look up the machine name environment variable and copy your file over connectionstrings.config. This way you can have multiple config files and the system will use the correct one depending on the environment.

You can also create a separate configuration setting and use that to determine which file to use in the pre-build script.

Comment: That's what I would do, you could also just add some code to change the config value used depending on the machine name rather than switiching out the whole file.